# Nodemon not watching files

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I setup Nodemon on a new folder but any changes I make aren't being watched.

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "express",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch ./ ./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "config": {
    "mongodbMemoryServer": {
      "version": "latest"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

and the directory structure is something like:

[image]

`app.js` defines all the middleware to be used but the server creation and port specification happens in `./bin/www`.

I am not sure why this format is being followed, but I was asked to work on this existing template and I tried to setup nodemon to make the development process easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> server creation and port specification happens in ./bin/www.

Which means that you need to run `./bin/www` instead of `app.js` (how can you start your server by running file that doesn't contain that logic).

You should be good to go with

```
"dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
```

> I am not sure why this format is being followed

Because it makes testing way easier (exporting the server object and loading it into your test files). Also because of logic separation.

Comment: the result is the same. Nodemon still doesn't work. For reference, this is my `./bin/www` file: https://ideone.com/NKwbkR and this is my `app.js` file : https://ideone.com/Fw4FdD

Comment: Is your server running? Are you using `npm run dev` to run your server? With your old setup `npm run dev` would not start the server so you would have probably noticed.

Comment: sorry, I was running `npm run start`

Comment: I thought that :)